Winter Bash 2018 Building Competition
This is the thread where we'll be tracking and voting on submissions for the 2018 Winter Bash building competition. This year, we're asking you to recreate a scene from a holiday song. This can be any song you like, just be creative and try to capture the theme of the holiday season.
Here's an example that could have been a nice submission to this competition from JKBrickworks:

Rules

Builds must be original content that has not been shared in any venue previously.
Builds may only use genuine LEGO elements.
Digital submissions are acceptable.
Builds should not use more than 1000 elements. We want this to be a relatively open competition based on creativity, and not an opportunity for you to show off that you have enough elements to build a life-sized reindeer. :)
Designs must conform to our community guidelines and must not contain content that a reasonable person would find offensive either to themselves or to a child.
All submissions must be submitted to this thread before the end of Winter Bash (January 2nd).

Let me know if you have any questions, and happy building!

Regarding the second rule, are digital submissions allowed (LDD for example) and when does the competition end?

Digital submissions are fine. I've updated the original post with the end date.

Don't rules "Builds may only use genuine LEGO elements" & "Digital submissions are acceptable" kind-of contradict each other? Also, why aren't blocks from clone brands allowed? Considering this is & "bricks" community rather than a "LEGO" community, why discriminate people who prefer or who own mostly bricks of other brands?

@JohnSlegers My guess is that only LEGO is aloud because TLG is the one providing the prizes.

Rockin' Around The Christmas Tree

(with Rock Monsters, naturally)
Detail shot:

Features:

A drummer with a mohawk
A keyboard player with an Afro (I call him Rockmaninoff)
A guitar player channeling Kiss
Two singers
One crazy-difficult-to-build Christmas tree


This is brilliant. Nicely done!

P.S. Is anyone is interested in how to build that tree, I'd be happy to post an answer on a question about it.

I'd certainly be interested in how you did that. Personally, I'd build an (extremely fragile) tree like that by stacking Travis bricks and then building out from there. It'd be cool to see exactly how you did it.

@AlexanderO'Mara - you got there too fast for me. I was going to use the lego versions of my band: https://scontent.fman2-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/11173372_858257724221431_3061592973924650721_n.jpg?_nc_cat=102&_nc_ht=scontent.fman2-1.fna&oh=3ceeccd736a79e3a4101b2c333067d16&oe=5CA7CBDC

A 1968 Ford Mustang reborn as a Christmas tree
The accompanying lyrics (with some minor changes to the original...):

Last Christmas, I gave you a car 
But the very next day you took it apart
This year, to save me from tears
I'm building you something special

This little build is an exercise in creativity in a constrained environment born out of necessity, as we're spending the holidays at my father-in-law and this 75884 is the only LEGO set nearby. So I started wondering how else could it be used and suddenly the inspiration struck me as I was looking at this part.
I've been always rooting for the scrawny "underdog" trees on the market, so this build was intended to depict one of those trees: a bit sparse, a lot asymmetrical, the ornaments are either too big, too small or too clumped, but still full of love and holiday spirit.

